# Intersection between OEIS-A050808 and OEIS-A080053

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, oeis

Is there any result on the intersection between A050808 and A080053:

[OEIS-A080053](http://oeis.org/A080053)  =  1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10,... (Exp(n) is further from an integer than any previous exp(k))

[OEIS-A050808](http://oeis.org/A050808)  =  1, 2, 18, 50, 127,... (Numbers n such that floor(exp(n)) is prime)

From the entry tables at OEIS this intersection includes only 1 and 2.

I would be interested if there are any larger numbers, which belong to both sequences,
or if there might be even infinitely many belonging to both sequences.

Does maybe anyone have information on that issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Given the irrationality of $e$ and the density of irrational multiples $(\mod 1)$, my first intuition says that there are several ones, but I may be wrong.

Comment: What's the motivation? Is there any reason to believe why there should or shouldn't be?